# Firebase: How to update multiple nodes transactionally? Swift 3

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application designed for cleaning services. In this application the employees (cleaners) can read a list of jobs (bookings) which have been made by multiple customers (Users).

All cleaners can read all bookings in Users node. Initially, when a booking is saved in the database by a user, the key `claimed:` has a value of  `“false”`,meaning it has not been claimed by a cleaner.

Whenever a cleaner wants to claim a job present in the list, he will have to touch a button which will make a request to Firebase Database to modify the value of key `claimed` to `true` at path  `/Users/UID/bookings/bookingNumber`

Only one cleaner at a time should be allowed to modify the value of `claimed` key. If multiple cleaners were allowed to modify the value of `claimed` key, other cleaners would end up claiming the same job. We don't want that to happen.

Furthermore, after a cleaner modifies the value of `claimed` key to `true`, we will need to make another request to path `CLeaners/UID/bookings/bookingNumber` in order to save the booking he has just claimed in the cleaners node.
    - According to the firebase docs, we use transactions whenever we want a resource to be modified by only one request at a time, if there are multiple concurrent requests trying to write to the same resource, one of them will succeed. 
But the problem with using transactions is that it enables writing to **only one path**, it does not enable writing **to multiple paths**.

How can I ensure that even though multiple users can read this path  `/Users/UID/bookings/bookingNumber`, only one user at a time can update it? And if the write is successful, further write to the second path   `Cleaners/UID/bookings/bookingNumber`.

We need to take into account that the client's internet connection can drop, the user can quit the app, or simply the phone will switch off unexpectedly any time in-between writing to the paths specified above.

The database structure is as follows

```
Root
  Cleaners
    UID
     bookings
       bookingNumber
         amount: “10”
         claimed: “true”


   Users
     UID
      otherID
        bookingNumber
          amount: “10”
          claimed: “true”

         bookingNumber
          amount: “50”
          claimed: “false”
```

To avoid any overwrites, I have decided to use Firebase transactions. I can write to a single node as transaction, but writing to the second node in the completion handler is not a solution since the cleaner's internet connection may drop or app could be quit before a response is received from the server, thus the code in the completion handler `{(error, committed,snapshot) in....`would not be evaluated and the second write would not succeed.

Another scenario would be:  first write is executed,
 1. response is received  in client app
 2. response is not yet received in client app
     and the user quits the app immediately. In this case the second write will never be executed since no code is yet evaluated after response is received (or not) in the completion handler, thus leaving my database in an inconsistent state.

---

From Firebase docs:

> Transactions are not persisted across app restarts
>
> Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across
>   app restarts. So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being
>   committed to your Firebase Realtime Database.

- Is it possible to write to multiple nodes in a Firebase Database using Firebase Transactions in Swift?

If so, how can I do this? I see no example in this blog from google https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html  . I do understand that you can write atomically to multiple nodes, but I'd like to write as transaction.
I am trying to write to two nodes in the `else` clause, but I get a warning on this line `let updated = updateInUsersAndCleaners as? FIRMutableData`

> Cast from '[FIRDatabaseReference : FIRMutableData]' to unrelated type 
>   'FIRMutableData' always fails

```
    class ClaimDetail: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

 var valueRetrieved = [String:AnyObject]()
 var uid:String?

   @IBAction func claimJob(_ sender: Any) {

      dbRef.runTransactionBlock({ (_ currentData:FIRMutableData) -> FIRTransactionResult in

//if valueRetrieved is nil abort
  guard let val = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject] else {
    return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
    }
          self.valueRetrieved = val

  guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
         return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
        }
              self.uid = uid

    for key in self.valueRetrieved.keys {
         print("key is \(key)")

   //unwrap value of 'Claimed' key
  guard let keyValue = self.valueRetrieved["Claimed"] as? String else {
              return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
        }

            //check if key value is true
               if keyValue == "true"{

                //booking already assigned, abort
                  return FIRTransactionResult.abort()

            } else {
              //write the new values to firebase
               let newData =  self.createDictionary()
                  currentData.value = newData

             let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("Users").child(FullData.finalFirebaseUserID).child(FullData.finalStripeCustomerID).child(FullData.finalBookingNumber)
            let cleanersRef = self.dbRef.child("Cleaners").child(self.uid!).child("bookings").child(FullData.finalBookingNumber)

  //Create data we want to update for both nodes
    let updateInUsersAndCleaners = [usersRef:currentData,cleanersRef:currentData]
                let updated = updateInUsersAndCleaners as? FIRMutableData
                  return FIRTransactionResult.success(withValue: updated!)

      }//end of else
}//end of for key in self

          return FIRTransactionResult.abort()
    }) {(error, committed,snapshot) in

        if let error = error {
            //display an alert with the error, ask user to try again

         self.alertText = "Booking could not be claimed, please try again."
             self.alertActionTitle = "OK"
               self.segueIdentifier = "unwindfromClaimDetailToClaim"
                  self.showAlert()

        } else if committed == true {

        self.alertText = "Booking claimed.Please check your calendar"
            self.alertActionTitle = "OK"
            self.segueIdentifier = "unwindfromClaimDetailToClaim"
               self.showAlert()
        }
    }

 }//end of claimJob button

}//end of class


  extension ClaimDetail {

//show alert to user and segue to Claim tableView
   func showAlert() {
      let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "", message: self.alertText, preferredStyle: .alert)
     alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: self.alertActionTitle, style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.segueIdentifier, sender: self)
    }))
         self.present(alertMessage, animated: true,completion: nil)
 }


    //create dictionary with data received from completion handler and the new data
  func createDictionary() -> AnyObject {
     let timeStamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
       self.valueRetrieved["CleanerUID"] = uid as AnyObject?
         self.valueRetrieved["TimeStampBookingClaimed"] = timeStamp as AnyObject?
         self.valueRetrieved["Claimed"] = "true" as AnyObject?
          print("line 89 extension CLaim Detail")
            return self.valueRetrieved as AnyObject
      }
   } // end of extension ClaimDetail
```

Comment: The blog post shows an example in Objective C. Are you having trouble translating this to Swift? If so: update your question to show what you've already tried.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't see any of the exmples using this function `runTransactionBlock` as explained in https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions . Should I just create two references to the different nodes in firebase database and then write the data as transaction? I couldn't find any exmple in the blog showing data being written to two different paths using firebase transactions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Please see my updated question

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen   I have answered my question and I would very much need your opinion on this matter. Many thanks

Comment: Hey @bibscy! It looks like you've made a lot of progress (and changes to the question) since I first commented. It looks like you're building an implementation. It's hard for me to provide feedback on it given the scope. Stack Overflow is simply not a good forum for reviewing application architecture. But if the chosen approach works for you, that's great. If it doesn't, share the minimal code that reproduces where you are now having an issue. That allows us to look at a small piece of code, instead of trying to understand your entire app.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. It's a lot more clear. Question: When a cleaner selects a job and claimed is set to true, why is there a 'hurry' to write that data to the bookings node i.e. it's not clear why both nodes need to be written within the same transaction; Once the claimed node is set to true, no other cleaners can access that job which means they could not write it to their own node. Doesn't setting claimed to true lock it down?

Comment: @Jay Your statement is perfectly true. Now, if the cleaner's node is not written in the same transaction, the transaction callback could not be relied on because the user could quit the app before response is received from firebase server thus 2nd write would fail. Another option: every cleaner should continuously observe the whole Users node, then loop through all users and all bookings in the database and if any of the bookings contained a CleanerUID that matched the login UID of the cleaner, then the cleaner would have to write that booking to his node at root/Cleaners/UID/bookings/4875383

Comment: I think you may be overly concerned about the user quitting the app. It's would literally be milliseconds between setting claimed to true and storing the job data in their node. Not sure if it would really be possible for the user to quit the app that quickly.

Comment: @Jay I am concerned about this scenario because most of the people in London where the app will be launched, are traveling using the underground train. It also goes overground too. Now, the cleaner is in the train, it it touches the Claim button, an activity indicator is displayed on the screen, `true` value is written to Users node, the train enters underground, signal is lost, activity indicator keeps showing, the response from the firebase server for the first write to Users node was not received, now user quits the app.

Comment: How about a scenario where the cleaner is on the train, goes underground *then* the cleaner touches the Claim button? It would appear the job was claimed but it wasn't. In your scenario, once it's claimed, nobody else can claim it. I still think that what I included in my answer is the way to go - the job info is already in the app (which is why the cleaner can select it) so when the cleaner claims the job write TRUE to the claimed node and write that data to the /users node at the same time.

Comment: @Jay the scenario you described is possible too. However, in the case your described, I think that after client goes offline and then online, the Firebase Realtime Database client synchronizes with the server before posting any write requests to the server and all queued operations would resume after synchronization is finished (I am only assuming, I can't find this info in the docs). The reason why I can't proceed with your answer is that writing data concurrently to multi-path using Firebase IOS SDK would enable multiple users to modify the /Users node concurrently.

Comment: @Jay continuing: ... I don't want that. E.g: Two or more users read root/users/UID/bookings/4875383, both users write in the same request both to /Users and /Cleaners nodes (/Users node can be written to by multiple users). One of the users will overwrite the other's data at root/users/UID/bookings/4875383 and that should not happen. As far as I know a multi-path write using the IOS client library is atomic, but not transactional.

Comment: The issue remains that if a user goes into a tunnel, taps a job to secure it and someone else tapped that job that has a connection, your tunnel user will try to sync when it gets a connection causing a conflict. So you'll need to add additional logic to prevent attempting to grab a job when the connection is lost. Lots to think about when you have potential race conditions or conflicts.

Comment: @Jay I guess my only option that is suitable for my use case would be to move all the code logic on a Vapor server and use [Conditional Request Over Rest as explained](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) in Firebase docs. In this way a user would make a request to my server which would further make other requests to Firebase servers to read/write the database. Thus, if mobile app loses internet connection or if app is quit after a request  to my server was made, would not cause loss of data integrity in Firebase Databse. Do you see this as a working solution for my case?

Comment: We have a similar situation with our apps - we watch the isConnected node and if the app d/c's for whatever reason, we notify the user and don't allow them to attempt to write any data. It generally prevents issues like this. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37218211/firebase-connection-manager-should-return-only-one-result/37227399#37227399) and some other info in my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817118/updating-label-if-value-in-singleton-changes/40819056#40819056)

Comment: @Jay I am building a chat app and I don't know what's the best practice in my particular case. Someone replied, but he's not very confident in his solution. Could you please advise me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Firebase documentation in the section [**Enable Offline Capabilities**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) it is specified that:

> Transactions are not persisted across app restarts
>   Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across
>   app restarts.
>   So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being
>   committed to your Firebase Realtime Database.

Therefore:
1. there is no way to use firebase transactions at client side to update a value at two or more paths.
2. using a completion callback to perform the second write is not viable since the client could restart the app before a response is received in the completion handler from the firebase server, thus leaving the database in inconsistent state.

I assume that my only option to update data transactionally at the first path and further update the second path with that data that was already written at the first path in Firebase Database, would be to use  [Conditional Requests over REST](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) as specified in the Firebase Documentation.
This would achieve the same functionality provided by Firebase framework for IOS clients.

- 1. The client will make a request via Alamofire to my server (I will use Vapor framework so as to leverage the Swift language), once the request is received at  the Vapor server, a GET request will be sent to the Firebase Database server `root/users/bookings/4875383` in which I will request an **ETAG_VALUE**

***What is ETAG Value?:*** ( a unique identifier which will be different every time data changes at the path where GET Request is made. Namely if another user writes to the same path before my write request the resource succeeds, my write operation will be rejected since the ETAG value at the path will have already been modified by the other user's write operation. This would enable users to write data transactionally to a path)

- 2. a response is received from the Firebase Server containing a an ETAG_VALUE.
- 3. make a PUT request to the Firebase Server and in the header specify the **ETag: [ETAG_VALUE]** received from the previous GET request. If the ETAG value posted to the server matches the value at the Firebase Server, the write will succeed. If the location no longer matches the ETag, which might occur if another user wrote a new value to the database, the request fails without writing to the location. The return response includes the new value and ETag.
- 4. Furthermore, now we can update the value at `root/Cleaners/bookings/4875383` to reflect the job that was claimed by a cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to write to multiple nodes in a Firebase Database using
>   Firebase Transactions in Swift?

The use case is not super clear as why a transaction is needed - it seems that data needs to be written to more than one node concurrently. If that's the case you can write to multiple nodes 'at the same time' without a transaction.

Here's an example. Given a structure

```
messages
  msg_0
    msg: "some message"
  msg_1
    msg: "another message"
  msg_2
    msg: "cool  message"
```

upon running the following code

```
let messagesRef = self.ref.child("messages")
let path0 = "msg_0/msg"
let path1 = "msg_1/msg"
let path2 = "msg_2/msg"

let childUpdates = [
    path0: "0 message",
    path1: "1 message",
    path2: "2 message"
]

messagesRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

the result is a simultaneous write:

```
messages
  msg_0
    msg: "0 message"
  msg_1
    msg: "1 message"
  msg_2
    msg: "2 message"
```

If that doesn't provide a solution, we probably need more clarity in the question about the use of the Firebase Transaction.

Comment: I have updated my original question. I don't need to write concurrently to the same resource. Only one request should succeed at a time. If 100 users would try to write to this resource at a time `/Users/UID/bookings/bookingNumber`, only one write request should succeed, all other 99 should fail.  Could I write to two different paths in the same transaction? I want to avoid writing to the second path `Cleaners/UID/bookings/bookingNumber` using the transaction completion handler  because the client could quit the app or run out of battery and the second write would never be executed.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. I think this example resembles my use case. To make it more similar to my case, you would have to assume that multiple clients are trying to debit the 'debit checking account' and credit their 'credit savings accounts'. I am wondering if this can be achieved with the Firebase IOS SDK client in Swift. 
 http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncii.html

Comment: I am trying to use your answer in order to update data at multiple paths, but I can't get it to work. Please see my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100421 . Many thanks

Comment: Firebase calls this feature "multi-path updates". Just in case you want to find it in their documentation.