# When to detach firebase listeners in tableView cell?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In chat app, in order to keep track of each chat's last message and unread messages for each user participating in chat, when the tableView cell is dequeued I am attaching a `.childChanged` listener on the cell. When the listener is fired, I update the chat label.text on each row for the corresponding chat.
When should I remove these listeners or what is the best practice to update the chat in the cell in my case?

What is the flow of the program?
1. Download current user
2. Download current user chatIDs
3. Download chat for each chatID
4. Populate tableView with chats
5. In each cell observe childChanged at
chats/chat.chatUID/currentUserUID/.observe(.childChanged)
6. If "unreadMessagesCount" was changed, update it on the cell

```
class ChatTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet weak var lastMessageLabel: UILabel!

    var chat: Chat! {
       didSet{
        self.updateUI()
     }
  }

  func updateUI() {

    self.chat.observeChildChanged(chat: self.chat, currentUserUID:user.userUID) { (lastMessage, unreadMessagesCount) in

        if !lastMessage.isEmpty{
            self.lastMessageLabel.text = lastMessage
        }

        if unreadMessagesCount > 0 {
            self.lastMessageLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
            self.chatUnreadMessagesCount.text = "\(unreadMessagesCount)"
        } else {
            self.lastMessageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
            self.chatUnreadMessagesCount.text = ""
        }
    }
  }
} 

 class MessagesViewController: UITableViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
      //observe ~/users/uid
       DDatabaseRReference.users(uid: uid).reference().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        guard snapshot.exists() else {return}

            if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                self.currentUser = UserModel(dictionary: userDict)
                self.userWasDownloaded = true //this will trigger the setter and start downloading chatId's of current user
            }
    })
 }

 var userWasDownloaded: Bool {
     get {
        return true
     }
     set {
        self.fetchChatsIdsOf(currentUser: self.currentUser)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
     }
 }


func fetchChatsIdsOf(currentUser: UserModel) {
     //get chatIds of currentUser from ~/users/currentUser.userUID/chatIds
    DDatabaseRReference.users(uid: currentUser.userUID).reference().child("chatIds").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let chatUID = snapshot.key
        if !self.chatIdsDownloaded.contains(chatUID) {
            self.chatIdsDownloaded.append(chatUID)
        }
    })
}

//after chatIdsDownloaded is set,
//download the new chat for the last chat appended to chatIdsDownloaded array
var chatIdsDownloaded = [String]() {
    didSet {
        guard let chatID = chatIdsDownloaded.last else  {return}
        self.downloadNewChat(chatID: chatID)
    }
}

    func downloadNewChat(chatID: String) {
   DDatabaseRReference.chats.reference().child(chatID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        ......
      self.currentUserChats.insert(chatChecked, at: 0)
     }
   }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
       cell.chat = currentUserChats[indexPath.row]
      return cell
    }
 } 



chats    // <- all chats in the app for all users in the app
 -LOMVtcjOEOu2p1apMKV
   chatUID: "-LOMVtcjOEOu2p1apMKV"
   isGroupChat: true
   lastMessage: "Katherine Gregory has joined the group"
   lastUpdate: 1539761870.2237191
   +users
     IN4pgCS5NqQZZLpdmoz1KeDiFqj2
     fcmToken: ""
     firstName: "Alex"
     userUID: "IN4pgCS5NqQZZLpdmoz1KeDiFqj2"
     unreadMessagesCount: 5



users   // <- all users in the app
 IN4pgCS5NqQZZLpdmoz1KeDiFqj2
   +chatIds
      -LOMVtcjOEOu2p1apMKV: true
      - name: ""
      - email: ""
       ...etc
```

Comment: I would not advise having listeners or that kind of logic within a cell - it may make your UI laggy. IMO tableViews are UI elements that are backed by a dataSource. When changes occur to data, update the dataSource and then reload the tableView which then updates the UI. Your viewController would add .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved observers to Firebase. When changes occur, your class is notified and you can update a dataSource array accordingly. I would suggest a child node called *is_read* that is false when it is not read so you can easily track read/unread messages.

Comment: when you begin listening `.onSnapshot` you download what's existing, then if and only if it (the path listened to) changes you'll get an update. So, no need to "download". Just `.onSnapshot` the stuff you want to pass to your UI/app.

Comment: @Jay I understand that data source should back the UI, but I don't know where to start from. I do have .childAdded, .childChanged, .childRemoved attached on `users/currentUserUID` and in this way I can read/delete/write the chatUID's for the currentUser. However once I read the chatUID's of the currentUser, I need to download the chats stored at `chats/chatUID`. Now, the problem is that I need to observe .childChanged, on each chat downloaded.  `unreadMessagesCount: 5` is a child of  `chats/chatUID/users/currentUserUID/ 
 unreadMessagesCount: 5.`

Comment: We don't know the structure but it should be a matter of adding .childAdded observers to each chat within the viewController (not each cell). That will read in each chat and then notify you of any newly added chats. I would start by having your tableView read it's data from a dataSource array, in the viewController have a function that handles .childAdded events which updates your dataSource accordingly with existing chat info upon init and will add new chat info when those events occur. e.g chat 3 has new chat, event will fire, update the dataSource array for chat 3, reload tableView.

Comment: I understand now, I'll get down to work. Thank you

Comment: @Jay, I did what you suggested, but for some reason the .childChanged observer does not get triggered always. Consider this key, value pair `name: "alex"` . If in firebase console, I change the value `alex` to `somethingelse` sometimes the listener is triggered, sometimes it is not. I use breakpoints to check, and none of them are hit   https://imgur.com/a/7wqVD9W

Comment: @Jay, I posted in Answers section the solution I have wrote, but it is not working as expected.

Comment: @Jay, I just wanted to thank you for the suggestion and let you know that the reason why `childChanged` was triggered only once was because I had forgotten to delete the previous implementation in the tableViewCell and in `prepareForReuse` I was detaching the listener for that particular chat.  `DDatabaseRReference.chats.reference().child(chat.chatUID).child("users").child(currentUser.userUID).removeAllObservers()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jay suggested, I am attaching `.childChanged` observer on each chat newly downloaded.
However, if I go to firebase console and update the value of a child at `ref` path, childChanged observer is not always triggered. Sometimes, it works, sometimes it does not What could be the problem?
I am using break points on all lines and none of them is hit when value is changed in database.

example: `name:`"Alex"
change with: name: "John"

**UPDATE**
This answer is correct, I had forgotten to delete my previous implementation in which was detaching the listeners in `prepareForReuse()`

```
var currentUserChats = [Chat]() {
    didSet(newValue){
       attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: newValue)
    }
}

var observersArray = [String: UInt]() // chatUID:handle


  func attachChildChangedObserverOn(chat: Chat) {

     var handle: UInt = 0
     let ref =   DDatabaseRReference.chats.reference().child(chat.chatUID).child("users").child(currentUser.userUID)
    handle = ref.observe(.childChanged, with: {[weak self] (snapshot) in

     self?.observersArray[chat.chatUID] = handle

        print("snapshot.value is \(snapshot.value) and snapKey is \(snapshot.key)")
        guard snapshot.exists() else {return}

        let chatChanged = chat

        var lastMessage = ""
        var unreadMessagesCount = 0
        var lastUpdate = 0.0

        switch snapshot.key {
        //case....
       }

     })

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you added 2 or more observers for cell.

Add breakpoint or print() here:

```
self.chat.observeChildChanged(chat: self.chat, currentUserUID: user.userUID) { (lastMessage, unreadMessagesCount) in {
   //breakpoint or print("observeChildChanged")
   ...
}
```

Please, reuse your cell.
Send new message.

If you have 2 or more messages it means that you have not set only one observer.

Perhaps this approach is not perfect, but it can help you (remove old observers before add new):

```
var chat: Chat! {
   didSet {
      self.removeOldObserver()
      self.updateUI()
   }
}

func removeOldObserver() {
   ...
}
```